# Removal of green color (>?) [for replies to inputs] that appears on IntelliJ-IDEA 2020.3 Python Console

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, console, settings

[A picture of my Python console in IntelliJ-IDEA Community Edition 2020.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnKjq.png)

There is a green colour (>?) that appears on my console in which I cannot remove.

I cannot type my input next to the "Name: " but instead can only type it in the line below, next to the (>?).

I am not sure how to remove this so that I can type my input in the same line as "Name: "

Comment: That's the prompt. It indicates that the console is listening to your command and not being in the middle of an execution. When you see that you can enter a command. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt    . Go ahead and type the name :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry about the prompt messing up your input - it is just Pycharm's way of signifying that it is waiting for an input. If you would like the prompt to not be shown so that you can take a screenshot or something, try running the script through any command line terminal or python's IDLE.